# Modify Queued Jobs Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

I am using redis queue on laravel and i have been struggling with it. Is it possible to retrieve a queued job and modify it with code?

For example if i need to add to delay or update content of email on the queued job.

Thanks

Comment: Similarly, I'm interested in learning how to delete a queued Mailable: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48255735/470749